# Unexpected behaviour from Simpify with Complexity Function and Transformation Rules

Tags: simplifying-expressions

While massaging an expression in Mathematica I get terms of the form $(-((-1 + z) z))^{-1 + \epsilon}$. However, $z$ is between $0$ and $1$ and thus I would prefer $((1 - z) z)^{-1 + \epsilon}$. Just using simplify gives me the undesired result, so I tried defining a complexity function for Simplify:

```
   Simplify[
     (-((-1 + z) z))^(-1 + \[Epsilon]), ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 
       100 Count[#, -1 + z, {0, Infinity}]) &]
```

This hower stll gives me $(-((-1 + z) z))^{-1 + \epsilon}$ so I tried to help Mathematica by telling it the transformation rule I want

```
tf[x_] := x /. -((-1 + z) z) :> z (1 - z);
 Simplify[(-((-1 + z) z))^(-1 + \[Epsilon]), 
   ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 100 Count[#, -1 + z, {0, Infinity}]) &, 
   TransformationFunctions -> {tf, Automatic}]
```

,which however still yields $(-((-1 + z) z))^{-1 + \epsilon}$. Finally, I told Mathematica to only use my transformation

```
   Simplify[(-((-1 + z) z))^(-1 + \[Epsilon]), 
   ComplexityFunction -> (LeafCount[#] + 
       100 Count[#, -1 + z, {0, Infinity}]) &, 
   TransformationFunctions -> {tf}]
```

, which finally yields $((1 - z) z)^{-1 + \epsilon}$. However, in general, I would like Mathematica to also check for other simplifications. I do not understand why Mathematica ends up with a worse complexity when using more possible simplifications.

Edit: Also adding assumptions as suggested by Mariusz Iwaniuk does not work and still yields the undesired result.

```
Simplify[(-((-1 + z) z))^(-1 + \[Epsilon]),   Assumptions -> {0 <= z <= 1, \[Epsilon] \[Element] Reals}]
```

Comment: To more simplified input: `Simplify[(-((-1 + z) z))^(-1 + \[Epsilon]), 
 Assumptions -> {0 <= z <= 1, \[Epsilon] \[Element] Reals}]`

Comment: Put the `&` inside the parentheses in your complexity function.

Comment: Why not use your `tf[x]` directly to pre-process the expression and then use `Simplify` for further simplifications? `Simplify` is almost a blackbox to users and hard to control.

Answer (score -1):

Let us try the following. First, let us introduce a function, factorMinus, which takes a sign minus out of the expression:

```
factorMinus[expr_, fun_ : Identity] := (-1)*
  HoldForm[Evaluate[fun[(-1)*expr]]]
```

Now one can apply this function to the term `-1+z`:

```
expr1 = MapAt[factorMinus, expr, {1, 2}] // ReleaseHold
(*  ((1 - z) z)^(-1 + \[Epsilon])   *)
```

Done. Have fun!